# Public hostname in Cloudflare Zero Trust Tunnel - Terraform resource

Tags: terraform, cloudflare

I feel stupid to ask about this but I cannot find Terraform resource for configuration of public host route inside the CloudFlare ZeroTrust Tunnel. Or maybe there is no such a config?

https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/connections/connect-apps/routing-to-tunnel/

[image: Editing tunnel...]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to expose a public DNS record that points to your Cloudflare Tunnel (so you can expose the resources behind the tunnel)?

If so, if you are using Cloudflare as your DNS provider, you can create a `cloudflare_record` ([docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/cloudflare/cloudflare/latest/docs/resources/record)) resource that points at the tunnel endpoint.

Here is some example code

```
resource "cloudflare_argo_tunnel" "prometheus_analytics" {
  account_id = var.cloudflare_account_id
  name       = "prometheus_analytics"
  secret     = base64encode(var.cloudflare_tunnel_secret)
}

resource "cloudflare_record" "prometheus_app" {
  zone_id = lookup(data.cloudflare_zones.configured_zone.zones[0], "id")
  name    = var.cloudflare_cname_record
  value   = "${cloudflare_argo_tunnel.prometheus_analytics.id}.cfargotunnel.com"
  type    = "CNAME"
  proxied = true
}
```

(The full tutorial is [explained here](https://www.paolotagliaferri.com/monitor-your-website-with-cloudflare-prometheus-grafana/))

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I've added a picture which shows which part I would like to have inside Terraform. It shows the panel after hitting `Configure` for a tunnel.

Comment: Understood, thanks. I believe this is not yet supported in Terraform, but you may want to follow this https://github.com/cloudflare/terraform-provider-cloudflare/issues/1756 as it covers what you are asking.